# Comparing values in different time frames (after resample and rolling in Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have fast timeframe (tick data) and want to check if the value is equal to maximum price of rolling max on 1 minute timeframe.

Tick data are:

```
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4243.00
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.75
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.50
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.50
2016-06-27 08:30:00    4242.50
```

I calculate the rolling max on 1 minute timeframe using:

```
rol=ntick.Last.resample('1min').max().rolling(center=False,window=4).max()
```

But what is the fastest way to check if value from tick data is equal to rolling max in rol?

I am still quite new to Python, so I can come only with very slow way using loop:

```
mask=[]
for x in range(0,len(ntick)):
    mask.append(ntick.Last[x]==rol[ntick.index[x].replace(second=0)])
```

and then apply mask as ntick['mask']=mask

This works but is not very efficient. Any tip how to do this better?

EDIT:

List comprehension instead of the loop makes the process 3x faster:

```
mask=[ntick.Last[x]==rol[ntick.index[x].replace(second=0)] for x in range(0,len(ntick))]
```

But still wondering if there is some better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you may want to use `Series.asof`, which returns last valid value and can take a list-like argument. I assume `ntick` (and also `rol`) has a sorted `DatetimeIndex` as an index.

```
rol2 = rol.squeeze().asof(ntick.index)
```

Initially, `rol` is a one-column data frame, so `squeeze` is necessary to turn it into a `Series`. Indexes of `rol2` and `ntick` are now equal and we can compare:

```
mask = ntick.Last == rol2
```